# Is it best-practice to place __init__ in the beginning or end of a class?

Tags: python, design-patterns

Consider the following code:

```
class AClass():

    def defaultMethod(self):
        return 1

    def __init__(self, methodToUse = defaultMethod):
        print (methodToUse(self))

if __name__== "__main__":
    AClass()
```

In this case one cannot move the defaultMethod below the __init__ method, if I do, it causes "NameError: name 'defaultMethod' is not defined"

This means that I need to define this method before the __init__ or else Python does not know about it. This again, means that I no longer have __init__ as the first method, which leaves me to wonder whether it is usual to place the __init__ method at the end of a class or in the beginning.

Comment: Post code. The order in which you declare methods shouldn't really be an issue unless you're doing something fairly strange.

Comment: I still don't see how a situation can require to have a certain ordering of methods in a class?  Could you give an example?

Comment: @David Having executed your code, I didn't observe any error

Comment: @eyquem Change the order of `defaultMethod` and `__init__` and you'll see the problem. The compiler cannot assign the default argument for the `methodToUse` argument as that symbol would not yet exist when `__init__` is created.

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean, "I need to define this method before the init or else Python does not know about it" ?

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.foo()
...     def foo(self):
...         print '42'
... 
>>> A()
42
```

I usually place __ init__() before other instance methods, but after class methods/property/attributes.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're doing things a little peculiarly. You should still put `__init__` high up if not the first method. Readability is key and `__init__` exposes what you expect the main instance fields to be.

Here are three alternatives. My preference is for the first as it documents the default method and will require the least modification to your code. The last works, but could be confusing for anyone having to maintain your code.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, method="foo"):
        if callable(method):
            method(self)
        else:
            getattr(self, method)()
    def foo(self):
        print "something"


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, method = None):
        if method is None:
            self.defaultMethod()
        else:
            method(self)
    def defaultMethod(self):
        print "foo"


def _defaultMethod(self):
    print self.x

class C(object):
    def __init__(self, method = _defaultMethod):
        self.x = "bleh"
        method(self)
    def anotherMethod(self):
        print "doing something else"
    def defaultMethodProxy(self):
        _defaultMethod(self)
```

Comment: I prefer the second solution, mostly because it is similar to how one handles having an empty list as a default parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`__init__` is most commonly placed at the beginning of a class since they are the first thing run when the class is instantiated. Since your situation requires it to exist further down in the class, it would be nice to other devs to leave a note in the comments for the class.

Comment: Comments are for messages to developers maintaining your code. Docstrings are for API users.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer init at the beginning and I would actually not write the class that way, but rather something like this:

```
class AClass():
    def __init__(self, methodToUse = 'defaultMethod'):
        print getattr(self, methodToUse)()

    def defaultMethod(self):
        return 1

if __name__== "__main__":
    AClass()
```

The problem is that at compile time (when the default arguments are created), there is no function `defaultMethod`, but if you use it inside `__init__`, then the method is there.